# Raspbian: Shairport doesn't work

Tags: raspbian, shairplay

I have Raspberry Pi with Raspbian. So, I try to install shareport with [this tuturial](http://computers.tutsplus.com/articles/using-a-raspberry-pi-as-an-airplay-receiver--mac-54316). Everything installed fine. But I can't see Pi from my macbook.

```
$ shairport -vv
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.front
Bound to address 0.0.0.0
Failed to bind to address ::
avahi: avahi_register
avahi: register_service
Listening for connections.
```

And nothing else. I have no idea what's going wrong.

**Edit:**

```
$ sudo ./configure
Configuring Shairport
OpenSSL found
libao found
PulseAudio or its dev package not found
ALSA or its dev package not found
Avahi client found
getopt.h found
CFLAGS: -D_REENTRANT
LDFLAGS: -lm -lpthread -lssl -lcrypto -lao -lavahi-common -lavahi-client
Configure successful. You may now build with 'make'

$ sudo make
cc -D_REENTRANT   shairport.c daemon.c rtsp.c mdns.c mdns_external.c mdns_tinysvcmdns.c common.c rtp.c player.c alac.c audio.c audio_dummy.c audio_pipe.c tinysvcmdns.c audio_ao.c mdns_avahi.c -lm -lpthread -lssl -lcrypto   -lao   -lavahi-common -lavahi-client   -o shairport

$ sudo make install
install -m 755 -d /usr/local/bin
install -m 755 shairport /usr/local/bin/shairport
```

Comment: Are you using 1.0-dev branch of shairport, as in the tutorial? Because it looks like 1.0 was rewritten. Add the full output of `configure` and `make` of shairport, because it doesn't look like it's "fine".

Comment: @Keith I'm using 1.0-dev branch of shairport as in the tutorial. Is this it? I can not see device, there is no question about the sound yet.

Comment: Try the 1.0 master branch, e.g., git clone https://github.com/abrasive/shairport.git

Comment: @Keith Nothing has changed.

Answer (score 1):

I was just trying to figure this out myself and found the solution after thumbing through what some ubuntu *meta-packages* include, which aren't necessarily in the raspbian repository.

The package you want is **libasound2-dev**. Install it first:

```
sudo apt-get install libasound2-dev
```

Then, run `./configure` and you'll notice ALSA is detected.

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/shairport $ ./configure
Configuring Shairport
OpenSSL found
libao found
PulseAudio or its dev package not found
ALSA found
Avahi client found
getopt.h found
CFLAGS: -I/usr/include/alsa -D_REENTRANT
LDFLAGS: -lm -lpthread -lssl -lcrypto -lao -lasound -lavahi-common -lavahi-client
Configure successful. You may now build with 'make'
pi@raspberrypi ~/shairport $
```

If you'd also like PulseAudio support for shairport, install **libpulse-dev**, then rerun `./configure`

```
sudo apt-get install libpulse-dev
```

Afterwards, `make` and `sudo make install` and you're good to go.

---

For reference, the complete `apt-get` list of packages to install for all capabilities prior to installing **shairport** is:

```
sudo apt-get install git libao-dev libssl-dev libcrypt-openssl-rsa-perl libio-socket-inet6-perl libwww-perl avahi-utils libmodule-build-perl libasound2-dev libpulse-dev
```

Lifted from: http://drewlustro.com/hi-fi-audio-via-airplay-on-raspberry-pi/